# SharePoint Online - HTTP Web Service time-out in Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-services

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow in a SharePoint online environment. It calls an HTTP Web Service method. When testing locally, the web service took over 3 mins to return a result.

I am leaning towards a time-out issue here. Is there a time-out in SharePoint Designer/SharePoint Online for HTTP Web Service execution? If yes what is the limit? And is there any way around it?

**Error can be found below:**

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 09/06/2017 04:28.
>   Details of last request: HTTP  to *WebServiceLink* Correlation Id: 
>   Instance Id: 3a5c6db5-6445-4aff-8b0a-056fd32cda3e
>
> System.Net.WebException: Exception encountered while processing the
>   HTTP request. Exception details: 'HttpClient.SendAsync task was
>   canceled. TraceActivityId=f1f51d35-6744-9e4f-99b1-50dc1db92dd4'.    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.HttpRequestWorkItemAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result, Int32& responseCode)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well. I am having the same issue and I've tried every possible solution but none of them worked. Apparently you had the same issue as per the description. Won't you mind if I asked you how you manage to resolve this issue. It would be better if you share a brief summary how you got rid of it.

Thanks in advance,

Waseem